# In MySQL, Different Results with VIEW vs TABLE when using @vars

Tags: mysql, create-table, create-view

I thought that using a view or a table or a temporary table would give me the same result.

I'm creating some output to be used in another statement that works with `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` but does not work with `CREATE VIEW`.

The output I'm creating uses fields from 3 joined tables. The interesting part is a new field I'm generating in the output using `IFs` and `@vars` to add an ordinal number within a group. Here's some sample data of the output w/o the ordinal field:

```
display_name  date_played  end_hcp
Alan          2017-08-23   720
Alan          2017-08-29   692
Alan          2017-09-26   694
Bill          2017-08-24   865
Bill          2017-09-02   868
Bill          2017-09-21   842 
Dave          2017-08-24   363
Dave          2017-08-31   339
Dave          2017-09-05   332
Dave          2017-09-15   348
Dave          2017-09-17   374
```

And here's what I want it to look like with the new Ordinal column added in:

```
display_name  date_played  end_hcp  Ordinal
Alan          2017-08-23   720      1
Alan          2017-08-29   692      2
Alan          2017-09-26   694      3
Bill          2017-08-24   865      1
Bill          2017-09-02   868      2
Bill          2017-09-21   842      3
Dave          2017-08-24   363      1
Dave          2017-08-31   339      2
Dave          2017-09-05   332      3
Dave          2017-09-15   348      4
Dave          2017-09-17   374      5
```

Here's the working code using a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS pre_ordinal;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pre_ordinal AS 
SELECT u.display_name,
       m.date_played,
       p.end_hcp
FROM `lwljhb_lwl_matches` AS m
JOIN `lwljhb_lwl_players` AS p
JOIN `lwljhb_users` AS u
ON    m.id = p.match_id AND
      p.player_id = u.id
WHERE league_seasons_id = 12 AND
      playoff_round = 0
ORDER BY u.display_name, m.date_played;

SELECT po.*,
  @rn := if ( @display_name = po.display_name,
        @rn + 1,
        if ( @display_name := po.display_name, 1, 1)
        ) as Ordinal
FROM pre_ordinal AS po
JOIN (select @rn := 0, @display_name:=null) x
ORDER BY po.display_name, po.date_played;
```

If I use a `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` the Ordinal column is nearly all 1's. I noticed that in each of the very few times I got an Ordinal >1 it was when the ids for the match table were consecutive (the records were in physical order?).

I want to use my SQL within a WordPress plugin to create a chart. The plugin for some reason won't work with multiple statements, so the `DROP TABLE;` `CREATE TABLE` approach doesn't fly, whereas `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` is only one statement and works, it just gets the wrong answer.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html says in part:

> ORDER BY is permitted in a view definition, but it is ignored if you select from a view using a statement that has its own ORDER BY.

Apparently, the truth about ORDER BY and views may be that it *always* ignores the ORDER BY.

Since the order of evaluation is crucial in your query, I don't think it's reliable to use a view.

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to get around the 2 statement problem?

Comment: Can I use an index on the view?  -- Nevermind, no index on views.

Comment: I would guess that some coding work to modify that WordPress plugin is needed.